# Checking if an array has a negative and duplicate numbers in it

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

I'm trying to check to see how many negative numbers in an arrays and check if there's any duplicate numbers in the same array.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n = 0;
int negative_count = 0;
int duplicate_count = 0;
// input lenght of the array
scanf("%d", &n);
getchar();
int arr[n];
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
    //input elements of the array
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    getchar();
}

int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(arr[i] < 0){
        negative_count++;
    }
    for(int j= i+1;j<len;j++){
        if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
            duplicate_count++;
        }
    }
}

printf("Number of negative numbers: %d\n", negative_count);
printf("Number of duplicates: %d", duplicate_count);

return 0;
}
```

Input

```
5
1 -1 2 3 -3
```

output

```
Number of negative numbers: 2
Number of duplicates: 0
```

the output for the negative number is correct, but the output for the duplicate is not what I wanted. It should've output 2 because 1 and -1 boht have the number one, and so does 3 and -3. How should I go about this?

Comment: OT: I assume you use `getchar` to get the newline or other space between the numbers? That's not needed. As any decent book or tutorial should have taught you, the `scanf` format `%d` will skip and ignore any leading white-space (which includes newlines).

Comment: On another note: Why `int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);`? You already *know* the number of elements in the array: It's the value of `n`. That smells of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), which is bad.

Comment: `-1` and `1` are *not* the same number. If you can convince your math-teachers that `-1` and `1` are the same then you have my admiration. ;) What you seem to want is the *absolute* values to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want 1 and -1 to count as the same number you should use the abs() function to use the absolute value when searching for "duplicates".

```
abs(-1) = 1
abs(1) = 1


-1 == 1               returns false
abs(-1) == abs(1)     returns true
```

also remember to include <stdlib.h> to use abs()

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code and it works, just need to use the abs() function for comparing the array. And I also got rid of some unnecesarry code.

Here's the new code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int n = 0;
int negative_count = 0;
int duplicate_count = 0;

// input length of the array
scanf("%d", &n);
int arr[n];

for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
    //input elements of the array
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(arr[i] < 0){
        negative_count++;
    }
    for(int j= i+1;j<n;j++){
        if(abs(arr[i]) == abs(arr[j])){
            duplicate_count++;
        }
    }
}

printf("Number of negative numbers: %d\n", error_count);
printf("Number of duplicates: %d", duplicate_count);

return 0;
}
```